# Is there a way to use ConcurrentDictionary.TryUpdate with a lambda expression?

Tags: c#, .net, concurrency

I have a simple scenario where I want to update the value of an existing item. Only [AddOrUpdate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee378664.aspx) method offers a delegate where I can update the old value. However I don't want to  add anything if the key does not exist. Also [TryUpdate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287117.aspx) method has no overloads that I can get the old value. Is there a way to do it with current API?

Here's the signature I am looking for:

```
bool TryUpdate(TKey key, Func<TValue,TValue> updateValueFactory)
```

Comment: There is no method that does this. Have you considered adding a special value if the key does not exist and treat that value the same as if the entry was not present?

Comment: @dtb Since I am writing a wrapper for this class, it's not possible to come up with an invalid key. I can specifically ask for it but that wouldn't be my first choice.

Comment: Actually, if you're writing a wrapper you can actually store items that wrap the value, hence letting you create your own special tombstone value. It would add a cost to every single use though.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have to be prepared to loop and perhaps call the `Func` more than once (the same as with the overload of `GetOrAdd` that uses one). This means that if the `Func` has side-effects, it will not appear to be atomic from the outside. Really, `Func`s shouldn't have side-effects, but they always have some cost so the possibility of repeat calls can't be ignored:

```
public static bool TryUpdate<TKey, TValue>(
  this ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue> dict,
  TKey key,
  Func<TValue, TValue> updateFactory)
{
    TValue curValue;
    while(dict.TryGetValue(key, out curValue))
    {
        if(dict.TryUpdate(key, updateFactory(curValue), curValue))
            return true;
        // if we're looping either the key was removed by another thread,
        // or another thread changed the value, so we start again.
    }
    return false;
}
```

As said, because it can loop, it's only atomic as observed from the outside if there are no side-effects in the `Func`.

(Edit: Deleting a potential short-cut that is really too fraught to generally be used, and likely to bite someone who tried it).